# equivalent function of subs() of matlab in mathematica

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I have a matlab m-file in order to draw an integral as below. I want to rewrite this code in mathematica but I don't know any equivalent function for subs()!! Does any body help me?

```
syms x y w;
fun = (-1/(4.*pi)).*log(x.^2+(y-w).^2);
integral = int(fun, w); 
res_l = subs(integral, w, -0.5);
res_u = subs(integral, w, 0.5);
res = res_u - res_l;
ezsurf(res, [-1,1]);
```

Comment: For those of us who know Mathematica but not Matlab, you could explain what subs is supposed to do?  Is it subscript formatting?

Comment: Subs is a way of substituting values for symbolic variables like x, y and w. Here's the doc http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/subs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent Mathematica operation is achieved using the `ReplaceAll` function Which can be written as follows.

```
Integrate[Sin[x], x] /. x -> 3
(*Out:  -Cos[3] *)
```

If you want to replace several values, that can be achieved thus:

```
Integrate[Sin[x], x] /. x -> # & /@ { 7, 5, 8, 11, 13}
(* Out: {-Cos[7], -Cos[5], -Cos[8], -Cos[11], -Cos[13]} *)
```

Or as suggested by Mr.Wizard a more compact and efficient method:

```
Integrate[Sin[x], x] /. x -> {7, 5, 8, 11, 13}
```

Comment: +1, however your second example is evaluating `Integrate` again for every value in the list.  Also, thanks to the `Listable` attribute of `Cos` you can write: `Integrate[Sin[x], x] /. x -> {7, 5, 8, 11, 13}`